# match or term query on a long property for exact match?

Tags: elasticsearch

My document has the following mapping property:

```
"sid" : {"type" : "long", "store": "yes", "index": "not_analyzed"},
```

This property has only one long value for each record. I would like to query this property. I tried the following two queries:

```
{
    "query" : {
        "term" : {
             "sid" : 10
        }
    }
}

{
    "query" : {
        "match" : {
             "sid" : 10
        }
    }
}
```

Both queries work and return the target document. My question: which one is more efficient? And why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both work like the same way as you mentioned. As distinguished from match query the term query matches documents that have fields that contain a term (**not analyzed!**). So my opinion is that term query is more efficient in your case, because no analyzing have to be done.
See:
http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-term-query.html

Answer (score 3):

You want to use a term query, and if you want to be even more effecient, use a filtered query so your results get cached.

```
GET index1/test/_search
{
  "query": {
    "filtered": {
      "filter": {
        "term": {
          "sid": 10
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: thanks a lot for the complete query. this is exactly what I am doing.